# 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'known_hosts' on ssh.connect()

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to connect ssh server using code below

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts"))
ssh.connect("10.1.3.2", username = "root")
```

but I get the following error message

```
Exception during testMethod !!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Qb/QbUnittest/QbUnittest.py", line 624, in __call__
    testMethod()
  File "testDropBear_send_file.py", line 31, in runMe
    ssh.connect("10.1.3.2", username = "root")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko-1.12.0-py2.7.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 326, in connect
    self._policy.missing_host_key(self, server_hostkey_name, server_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko-1.12.0-py2.7.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 71, in missing_host_key
    client.save_host_keys(client._host_keys_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko-1.12.0-py2.7.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 192, in save_host_keys
    if self.known_hosts is not None:
AttributeError: 'SSHClient' object has no attribute 'known_hosts'
```

Can someone help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/176) and the fix was released to version 1.12.1; you seem to be using 1.12.0. Try upgrading to the latest release:

```
pip install --upgrade paramiko
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.known_hosts = None
...
...
```

The `bug` was fixed [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/176/commits/026739aef57143fb606bec32dcff49c632cfe738).